# Point predictions and prediction intervals

Tags: time-series, self-study

[image]

I am having trouble getting started with this question. Is there a formula for finding point predictions and prediction intervals? Any advice or hints would be great!

Let $\varepsilon$ be defined as white noise.

Does $X_{81}$= 0.8*$X_{80}$ -0.2* $\varepsilon_{80}$?
Does $\varepsilon_{81}$ =$X_{81}$-0.8*$X_{80}$- 0.2*$\varepsilon_{80}$?

Does $X_{82}$ = 0.8*$X_{81}$ -0.2*$\varepsilon_{81}$?

Comment: What's $w$? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Why are the coefficients on your error term changing? (-0.3 to -0.2)

Comment: I use $w$ as white noise. I edited my post to add the definition.

Comment: @garciaj sorry about that, I mistyped it

Comment: How does $w$ differ from the $\varepsilon$ in the question?

Comment: @Glen_b it doesn't differ at all, I just didn't know how to write the white noise symbol using MathJax

Comment: **\$\varepsilon\$** ... see [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols#Greek_Letters) for more. Someone else has inserted $\epsilon$ (**\$\epsilon\$**) instead of $\varepsilon$.